# What is the DDR4/5 Colum-to-Column access latency for within bank access

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, sdram, ddr, ddr4

Since DDR4, the banks are divided into bank-groups, where Column-to-Column delay (CCD) for accessing in different bank-groups is lower (tCCD_s) than than of accessing bank-to-bank within a bank-group (tCCD_l).

From Micron Brief of DDR5 SDRAM:

> Bank-group-to-bank-group interleaved timing accesses are shorter than
> bank-to-bank within a specific bank group access. These timing
> parameters have “long” timing definitions (tCCD_L, tWTR_L, tRRD_L) and
> “short” timing definitions (tCCD_S, tWTR_S, tRRD_S). The long timings
> refer to bank-to-bank within a bank group, while the short timings
> refer to accessing different bank groups

My question is: what is the access latency of sequentially accessing columns WITHIN a single bank. To be clear: do not change the row, do not change the bank-group OR the bank, just access the next 8n or 16n words from the same bank.

Is it equal to tCCD_l because I am accessing within the bank-group?

Or is it tCCD_s because I am not going bank-to-bank?

To me, the latter makes sense, since we do not need to switch to another bank within the bank-group. If I am wrong here, what is the reason for that?